# The proper way to validate a form with php (or possibly something else; aka AJAX)

Tags: php, ajax, validation

How is this done. Now, let me go into some more detail. I want to make a professional or at least professional seeming validation method for all my forms, from now onwards with my career. I hear a lot about using AJAX now to properly validate some fields before the user has even left the page, this interests me.

Here is my example form;

```
<form action="<?=$frontend['url']?>php/php-login-submission.php" method="post" id="loginForm">
    <table width="300px" border="0px" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <td><label><b>Email:</b></label></td>
        <td align="right"><input name="email" type="text" id="email" placeholder="registered@email.co.uk" tabindex="1" title="email" size="30" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label><b>Password:</b></label></td>
        <td align="right"><input name="password" type="password" id="password" placeholder="********" tabindex="2" title="password" size="30" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right"><input type="submit" id="loginBtn" value="Login" /></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Using AJAX, and php, how can i properly validate this form. I dont mind sending the data to an intermediate page such as `php/php-login-submission.php` to then have it redirect them to the `pages/members-area.php` if they pass validation.

So far i've been using such methods as;

```
if (!isset($_POST['email']))    $_SESSION['errortext'] = 'You must provide an email.';
```

And then just printing the `$_SESSION['errortext']` on the original page. This feels a bit scrappy.

I am completely new to AJAX and I'm not hugely confident with Javascript.

By the way, if this is a lil' on the daft side for a question, then just let me know and I have no issue just deleting it. Thanks in advance,

Alex.

Comment: If your goal is to go professional and you are "kind-of" new to web development I advice you to go and use some of the great frameworks out there: CakePHP, CodeIgniter, Symfony etc. They include really good documentation, and tutorials on how to build great apps, and enforce the MVC coding pattern - so your project wont be a big mess :)

The documentation of these frameworks also include howto's for AJAX.

If you would like to use AJAX or js in general, you should take a look at jQuery

Comment: thanks, ill be certain to look into it.

Comment: It is a login form. I can't think of any possible benefit in using Ajax for validation here. For a sign up form you could check to see if a username was available, but there isn't any data kept on the server that is useful for validation of a login form.

Comment: Well quentin, i was just trying to keep it simple for an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I use two methods first on the client side I use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQuery validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) so that I'm not putting more work on my server then when I submit the form I check everything again to make sure nothing got through the cracks. But that's just how I do it might not be the "best" way

Comment: Can we be a little more specific when answering? This came up as a top result for "proper way to validate form with php" shame it doesn't provide a good technique or some code snippet :(.

Comment: @KirillFuchs i understand your frustrations but the questions I find to be to broad for an answer that fits the space. To Me the question is like asking how to build a house and so i've offered a starting point rather than an instructional book.